# how do I get a list of all descendant nodes related to its parent node in rows in tsql?

Tags: t-sql, nodes

as a sample, my table (table name: hier) looks like this:

```
parentID childID
-------- -------
0        1
1        2
1        3
2        5
2        8
3        4
3        6
3        7
4        9
```

and I want it to output this:

```
parentID RelatedID
-------- ---------
0        1
0        2
0        3
0        4
0        5
0        6
0        7
0        8
0        9
1        2
1        3
1        4
1        5
1        6
1        7
1        8
1        9
2        5
2        8
3        4
3        6
3        7
3        9
4        9
```

Answer (score 1):

```
With cte(p, d)
As
(
    Select a.parentID, b.childID From hier a inner join hier b on a.childID=b.parentID
)
Select * From cte Union Select * From hier
```

Comment: BTW, it's hard to see in your data, but if there is more than one level of hierarchy, you can just use recursive CTE. See this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx